# Ending Up with Extra Null Values in ArrayList from SQL Reader

Tags: powershell

In short I am pulling data from a SQl stored procedure into an ArrayList of a custom class and I am somehow ending up with extra null items. One for each item pulled back, so if there are 15 items returned from the SQL stored procedure, I end up with an array of 30. Any help figuring out why I am getting extra items, or how to remove them would be greatly appreciated.

```
Function Execute-Procedure
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$parameter,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]$sqlconnection
    )
Process
{
 $items = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
 $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
 $cmd.Connection = $sqlconnection
 $cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
 $cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'
 $cmd.CommandText = "My_Stored_Procedure"
 $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARAMETER",$parameter) | Out-Null
 $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
 while($reader.Read())
 {
      $currentItem = [CustomClass]::new()
      $currentItem.property1 = $reader.GetValue(0)
      $currentItem.property2 = $reader.GetValue(3)
      $items.Add($currentItem)
 }
 $cmd.Dispose() | Out-Null
 $reader.Dispose()
 return $items
}
}

...

$items = Execute-Procedure $parameter $sqlconnection
$itemCount = $items.Count
"Item count: $itemCount"
foreach($item in $items)
{
     $p1 = $item.property1
     $p2 = $item.property2
     "Property1: $p1 - Property2: $p2"
}
```

Some sample output:

```
Item count: 30
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1:  - property2: 
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                           
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                  
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                                
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                 
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                            
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                        
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                                   
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                               
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                                        
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                      
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                                      
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                           
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX                      
property1: 1111 - property2: XXXX
```

Comment: You keep updating the same instance of `[CustomClass]` over and over again. You'll want to create a new instance every time inside the `while` loop

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow - you should always include a capture of the output to help people.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried that, and I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Just to get it right - `$items.Count` is 30 even though you only expect 15 items based on the query - and 15 of the items in the array list are `$null`? Every other? The last 15? The first 15?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes exactly. I just added some sample output. Sorry I had to redact information from it.

Comment: @Mirv-Matt sample output added.

Comment: They output you've shown is simply not possible with the code you've provided. If you re-use the same `[CustomClass]` instance, then all items would be the exact same. There must be something you're not showing us

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the only difference was that I was calling the SQL stored procedure in a function. I updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need to suppress the output from `ArrayList.Add()`

When you call `Add()` on an `[ArrayList]`, it returns the index at which the object was inserted.

Since PowerShell gladly surfaces *any output* to the caller, your function output ends up consisting of the numbers 0 through 14 and then the 15 objects - and dereferencing "property1" on an integer just results in `$null`

Solving it is as simple as:

```
$null = $items.Add($currentItem)
# or
[void]$items.Add($currentItem)
# or 
$items.Add($currentItem) |Out-Null
```

... inside the `while` loop